# Odoo 9 website user self password change

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

My question is simple, where does a client change his/her password after signing up (registering)?

I've installed odoo 9 (on Ubuntu) and installed the website app.

1. The Sign in page doesn't show a forgot username / password option
2. If the user logs in, the app has a "username -> My Account -> Your Details -> change" button, where the user can see address, e-mail ...etc. but no change password button.

Am I overlooking an option somewhere? If that option doesn't exist, is it possible to add such a button in xml, that would not be overwritten with the nightly builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! ...
In the url of your site, place ?debug after "web" and before "#"
(ex: server.tld:8123/web?**debug**#view_type=form...)
- select "settings" from the top menu
- click on "General Settings" on the left menu
- click on the checkbox next to "Enable password reset from Login page"
- click on apply
- remove ?debug from the url

Done!